# Updating a ScriptProperty to avoid retrieving duplicate Twitter statuses

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-apps-script

I was interested in writing a twitter bot to help out some friends at a local ski resort.  I found this tutorial from Amit Agarwal which gave me enough to get started (it did take me more than 5 minutes since I did a lot of modifying).  I host the script on google docs.

**FIRST** I *think* this is javascript (my understanding is that google apps script uses javascript...) and when I have had problems with the code so far, google searches for javascript-such-and-such have been helpful, but if this is not actually javascript, please let me know so I can update the tag accordingly!

I have no prior experience with javascript, so I am pretty happy that it's actually working.  But I want to see if I'm doing this right.

The `start` function initiates the trigger, which kicks off the `fetchTweets()` function every interval (30 minutes).  In order to avoid duplicates (the first errors I encountered) & potentially being flagged as spam, I needed a way to ensure that I was not posting the same tweets over and over again.  Within the `start()` function, the initial `since_id` value is assigned:

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID",        "404251049889759234");
```

Within the `fetchTweet()` function, I *think* I am updating this property with the statement:

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID", lastID + '\n');
```

**Is this a good way to do this? Or is there a better/more reliable way? And if so, how can I be *sure* it's updating the property?** (I can check the log file and it seems to be doing it, so I probably just need to create a permanent text file for the logger).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
/**     A  S I M P L E   T W I T T E R   B O T           **/
/**     =======================================          **/
/**     Written by Amit Agarwal @labnol on 03/08/2013    **/
/**     Modified by David Zemens @agnarchy on 11/21/2013 **/
/**     Tutorial link: http://www.labnol.org/?p=27902    **/
/**     Live demo at http://twitter.com/DearAssistant    **/
/**     Last updated on 09/07/2013 - Twitter API Fix     **/


function start() {

  Logger.log("start!" + '\n')

  // REPLACE THESE DUMMY VALUES
  // https://script.google.com/macros/d/18DGYaa-jbaAK9rEv0HZ2cMcWjFGgkvVcvr6TfksMNbbu2Brk3gZeZ46R/edit
  var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY     = "___REDACTED___";
  var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET  = "___REDACTED___";
  var TWITTER_HANDLE           = "___REDACTED___";  
  var SEARCH_QUERY             = "___REDACTED___" + TWITTER_HANDLE;

  // Store variables
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY",    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET", TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("TWITTER_HANDLE",          TWITTER_HANDLE);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("SEARCH_QUERY",            SEARCH_QUERY);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID",        "404251049889759234");

  // Delete exiting triggers, if any
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers();

  for(var i=0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  // Setup trigger to read Tweets every 2 hours

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("fetchTweets")
          .timeBased()
          .everyMinutes(30)
          //.everyHours(2)
          .create();

}

function oAuth() {
//Authentication
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY"));
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET"));

}

function fetchTweets() {

  oAuth();
  // I put this line in to monitor whether the property is getting "stored" so as to avoid
  // reading in duplicate tweets.
  Logger.log("Getting tweets since " + ScriptProperties.getProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID"))

  var twitter_handle = ScriptProperties.getProperty("TWITTER_HANDLE");
  var search_query = ScriptProperties.getProperty("SEARCH_QUERY")
  Logger.log("searching tweets to " + search_query + '\n');


  // form the base URL
  // restrict to a certain radius ---:
  //var search = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=5&geocode=42.827934,-83.564306,75mi&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&q="; 

  // unrestricted radius:
  var search = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=5&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&q="; 

  search = search + encodeString(search_query) + "&since_id=" + ScriptProperties.getProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID");    

  var options =
  {
    "method": "get",
    "oAuthServiceName":"twitter",
    "oAuthUseToken":"always"
  };

  try {

    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(search, options);    
    var lastID = ScriptProperties.getProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID"); 
    if (result.getResponseCode() === 200) {

      var data = Utilities.jsonParse(result.getContentText());

      if (data) {

        var tweets = data.statuses;
        //Logger.log(data.statuses); 
        for (var i=tweets.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
          // Make sure this is a NEW tweet

          if (tweets[i].id > ScriptProperties.getProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID")) {
            lastID = (tweets[i].id_str); 
            var answer = tweets[i].text.replace(new RegExp("\@" + twitter_handle, "ig"), "").replace(twitter_handle, "");

            // I find this TRY block may be necessary since a failure to send one of the tweets 
            // may abort the rest of the loop.
            try {

              Logger.log("found >> " + tweets[i].text)
              Logger.log("converted >> " + answer + '\n');

              sendTweet(tweets[i].user.screen_name, tweets[i].id_str, answer.substring(0,140));   

              // Update the script property to avoid duplicates.
              ScriptProperties.setProperty("SINCE_TWITTER_ID", lastID);

              Logger.log("sent to @" + tweets[i].user.screen_name + '\n'); 
            } catch (e) {

              Logger.log(e.toString() + '\n');

            }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString() + '\n');
  }

    Logger.log("Last used tweet.id: " + lastID + + "\n")
}

function sendTweet(user, reply_id, tweet) {

  var options =
  {
    "method": "POST",
    "oAuthServiceName":"twitter",
    "oAuthUseToken":"always"    
  };

  var status = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

  status = status + "?status=" + encodeString("RT @" + user + " " + tweet + " - Thanks\!");
  status = status + "&in_reply_to_status_id=" + reply_id;


  try {
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(status, options);

    Logger.log("JSON result = " + result.getContentText() + '\n');    
  }  
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString() + '\n');
  }


}

// Thank you +Martin Hawksey - you are awesome

function encodeString (q) {

  // Update: 09/06/2013

  // Google Apps Script is having issues storing oAuth tokens with the Twitter API 1.1 due to some encoding issues.
  // Henc this workaround to remove all the problematic characters from the status message.

  var str = q.replace(/\(/g,'{').replace(/\)/g,'}').replace(/\[/g,'{').replace(/\]/g,'}').replace(/\!/g, '|').replace(/\*/g, 'x').replace(/\'/g, '');
  return encodeURIComponent(str);

//   var str =  encodeURIComponent(q);
//   str = str.replace(/!/g,'%21');
//   str = str.replace(/\*/g,'%2A');
//   str = str.replace(/\(/g,'%28');
//   str = str.replace(/\)/g,'%29');
//   str = str.replace(/'/g,'%27');
//   return str;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ScriptProperties.setProperty("KEY", "VALUE");`, internally Script Properties will overwrite a duplicate key (i.e., if an old Property has the same key, your new one will replace it). So in your case, since you are using the same *identifier* for the key (`SINCE_TWITTER_ID`), it **will** replace any previous Script Property that is *that key*.

Furthermore, you can view Script Properties via `File` -> `Project properties` -> `Project properties (tab)`. Imo Google didn't name that very well. **User properties** as specific to Google users. **Script properties** as specific to the Script Project you are working under.

Also, it probably isn't a good idea to include `\n` in your value when you set the property. That will lead to all sorts of bugs down the road, because you'll have to compare with something like the following:

`var valToCompare = "My value\n";`

instead of:

`var valToCompare = "My value";`

because the value in `SINCE_TWITTER_ID` will actually be `"some value\n"` after you call your `fetchTweet()` function.

Of course, one seems more logical I think, unless you really need the line breaks (in which case you should be using them somewhere else, for this application).

Comment: *it probably isn't a good idea to include \n* (I did notice this and made the change :) thanks. I only want the line breaks in the logger, and I noticed I had inadvertently included that `\n` in the script properties assignment.  Thanks for a good explanation!

Comment: Yeah, no worries haha. I do things like that all the time, especially when I'm building up a system and making sure that everything is working correctly by spamming `Logger.log()` calls :P **PS** - GAS back-end is ECMA-standard Javascript. So you can do anything you can in standard Javascript, in addition to using GAS to access Google services such as: Calendar, Gmail, Spreadsheets, etc. You could also use GAS to develop a UI to let people schedule reservations with the ski resort if you wanted ;) it's an **incredibly** useful business tool!

Comment: Thanks! I am just scratching the surface here, I will need to learn some javascript for my day job and I've found the easiest way to learn a skill is by doing it for something other than *work*; so I'm going to explore the sort of options I can do just for my own hobbies, etc.

Comment: so `scriptProperties` object is like a `dictionary` of key/value pairs?  (I told you I know nothing about javascript :))

Comment: You are correct - `ScriptProperties` are basically a dictionary of key-value pairs, which are stored for a particular Script Project. But they aren't *JavaScript*, they're actually part of Google's Services (Google Apps Script-specific). So you can do *everything* in JS that you want (normal scripting capabilities), **in addition to** accessing *all of Google's Services*. You can read up on [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and look at all the documentation for their services ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its ok like that thou I dont know why you are adding \n at fhe end. Might confuse other code. You can see script properties in the script's file menu+ properties